# ACF Group type not working and the if inside PHP tag hide the section1 in the front end

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

```php
<?php $section1 = get_field('section1'); ?>
    <div class="section1" id="section1">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><?php echo $section1['title']; ?></h2>
            <div class="quote-triangle">
                <p>
                    <?php echo $section1['quote']; ?>
                </p>
                <div class="quote__moving-border"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                <div data-aos="fade-down">
                    <div class="leftside">
                        <h3>
                            <?php echo $section1['title_image']; ?>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="caption"><?php echo $section1['caption_image']; ?></div>
                        <div class="desc">
                            <p>
                                <?php echo $section1['desc_image']; ?>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-aos="fade-down">
                    <div class="rightside">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $secttion1['image']['url'] ); ?>" alt="" class="rightside__img">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I had followed literally the ACF documentation for the GROUP type but when I put the if in the PHP tag the whole section disappears and when I remove if the section back but The Group type still not worked.

Comment: Your code and explanation are totally incomplete. Please, post the whole code and also explain better the problem.

Comment: I am working on the ACF Plugin in WordPress but the Group type not working

Comment: Edit code block

Comment: what do you get when you `var_dump($section1)` - that should tell you how to make use of the returned result.

Comment: @KaiQing I got NULL what does that mean? where is the problem exactly

Comment: I figure it, the problem was that I use **section1** many times in my code especially in **Group type in the ACF Plugin** thanks, guys.

Comment: I changed the name of the **seciton1** and it's run correctly.